# md5sum issue when calling a service from another computer

Tags: ros, md5, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS on two computers. The master and it is the one requesting the service. The other is the one to which my robot is connected, and the one providing the service I wish to use (move the robot to a point).

When I try to request the service, the following error shows:

```
unable to connect to service: remote error reported: client wants service /enhance/MoveRobotToPoint to have md5sum 78ad5397dff8517113a4ce521add09a7, but it has 3b74f5e1707ea77798238c7e929349b7. Dropping connection.
```

Then, I noticed that the .srv files in the machines were different. By running the command

```
rossrv md5 MoveRobotToPoint
```

I noticed that the md5sum was indeed `78ad5397dff8517113a4ce521add09a7` on the ROS Master and `3b74f5e1707ea77798238c7e929349b7` on the server.
So, I changed the files so they were the same (and then built the workspace again, sourced devel/setup.bash and restarted the computer). The error still occurs! However, with the above command, I get for both machines `78ad5397dff8517113a4ce521add09a7`. So, I am pretty sure the md5sum is correct.

Could it be that somehow the service still "thinks" that the .srv file is the old one? How can I force him to update? I even deleted the hidden ~/MoveRobotToPoint.srv backup file.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245932/md5sum-issue-when-calling-a-service-from-another-computer/) by [s1839705](https://answers.ros.org/users/28000/s1839705/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try deleting catkin_ws/build and catkin_ws/devel and rebuilding.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-11-28**:
sorry @lucasw, I get this error is it that same? I am playing a bag file and trying to do rostopic echo /nav_status. Maany thanks

```
ERROR] [1638125363.279734078]: Client [/rostopic_28339_1638125362937] wants topic /nav_status to have datatype/md5sum [marta_msgs/NavStatus/ccb836e840c83634382508157bfdb91e], but our version has [marta_msgs/NavStatus/2652576ed189854bff45893603a05bc0]. Dropping connection.
```

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-11-28**:
The bag could have been recorded with a different (older?) version of `NavStatus`, if you can track it down you could compile it in a catkin_ws just for playing back the bag with.  Or look into https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_msg_parser or https://github.com/StefanFabian/ros_babel_fish if you don't know what the different NavStatus is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the answer given by lucasw would have worked. I solved the problem by typing 'make' in the command line in the directory catkin_ws/build/<package_name>

---

Originally posted by [s1839705](https://answers.ros.org/users/28000/s1839705/) with karma: 11 on 2016-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucasGV](https://answers.ros.org/users/70888/lucasgv/) on 2021-03-04**:
This solution worked for me, thnk you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also make sure your

```
nh.advertiseService<my_package::my_service::Request, my_package::my_service::Response>("service_name", 
        [&](my_package::my_service::Request &req, my_package::my_service::Response &res) -> bool
        {...});
```

and

```
nh.serviceClient<my_package::my_service>("service_name");
```

is consistent.

The error can happen when the service type advertised and the service type of the client to is different.

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-04-22**:
+1. FYI in my case, the error said `[/unnamed]`, which didn't give much hints but still looked different from other issues where the cause is checksum discrepancy.

```
Service call failed: unable to connect to service: remote error reported: request from [/unnamed]: md5sums do not match vs...
```